# Using make to setup openssl results in "Please run the same make command again"

Tags: android, makefile, openssl, android-ndk

Im making an ndk build for android, but I need to do https requests so im using openssl. I wanted the setup of the project to be automatic but I keep getting "Please run the same make command again" error every time I run the setup within make but its fine running the commands in the console.

```
androidVersion:=28
ndkRoot = $(shell pwd)/../android/ndk/25.2.9519653#https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/
opensslDir = ./openssl# Download from https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/latest ...

openssl:
    export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=$(ndkRoot) ; \
    PATH=$$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:$$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:$$PATH ; \
    cd $(opensslDir); \
    ./Configure android-arm -D__ANDROID_API__=$(androidVersion); \
    $(MAKE) ; \
    $(MAKE) ; \
    $(MAKE)
```

output:

```
> make -B
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/me/a/../android/ndk/25.2.9519653 ; \
PATH=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:$PATH ; \
cd ./openssl; \
./Configure android-arm -D__ANDROID_API__=28; \
make ; \
make ; \
make ; \

Configuring OpenSSL version 3.1.2 for target android-arm
Using os-specific seed configuration
Created configdata.pm
Running configdata.pm
Created Makefile.in
Created Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL.md file first)      ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/a/openssl'
Detected changed: Configure config build.info crypto/build.info ssl/build.info apps/build.info util/build.info tools/build.info fuzz/build.info providers/build.info doc/build.info test/build.info engines/build.info crypto/objects/build.info crypto/buffer/build.info crypto/bio/build.info crypto/stack/build.info crypto/lhash/build.info crypto/rand/build.info crypto/evp/build.info crypto/asn1/build.info crypto/pem/build.info crypto/x509/build.info crypto/conf/build.info crypto/txt_db/build.info crypto/pkcs7/build.info crypto/pkcs12/build.info crypto/ui/build.info crypto/kdf/build.info crypto/store/build.info crypto/property/build.info crypto/md4/build.info crypto/md5/build.info crypto/sha/build.info crypto/mdc2/build.info crypto/hmac/build.info crypto/ripemd/build.info crypto/whrlpool/build.info crypto/poly1305/build.info crypto/siphash/build.info crypto/sm3/build.info crypto/des/build.info crypto/aes/build.info crypto/rc2/build.info crypto/rc4/build.info crypto/idea/build.info crypto/aria/build.info crypto/bf/build.info crypto/cast/build.info crypto/camellia/build.info crypto/seed/build.info crypto/sm4/build.info crypto/chacha/build.info crypto/modes/build.info crypto/bn/build.info crypto/ec/build.info crypto/rsa/build.info crypto/dsa/build.info crypto/dh/build.info crypto/sm2/build.info crypto/dso/build.info crypto/engine/build.info crypto/err/build.info crypto/comp/build.info crypto/http/build.info crypto/ocsp/build.info crypto/cms/build.info crypto/ts/build.info crypto/srp/build.info crypto/cmac/build.info crypto/ct/build.info crypto/async/build.info crypto/ess/build.info crypto/crmf/build.info crypto/cmp/build.info crypto/encode_decode/build.info crypto/ffc/build.info apps/lib/build.info providers/common/build.info providers/implementations/build.info doc/man1/build.info providers/common/der/build.info providers/implementations/digests/build.info providers/implementations/ciphers/build.info providers/implementations/rands/build.info providers/implementations/macs/build.info providers/implementations/kdfs/build.info providers/implementations/exchange/build.info providers/implementations/keymgmt/build.info providers/implementations/signature/build.info providers/implementations/asymciphers/build.info providers/implementations/encode_decode/build.info providers/implementations/storemgmt/build.info providers/implementations/kem/build.info providers/implementations/rands/seeding/build.info Configurations/00-base-templates.conf Configurations/10-main.conf Configurations/15-android.conf
/usr/bin/perl configdata.pm -r
Configuring OpenSSL version 3.1.2 for target android-arm
Using os-specific seed configuration
Created configdata.pm
Running configdata.pm
Created Makefile.in
Created Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL.md file first)      ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
**************************************************
***                                            ***
***   Please run the same make command again   ***
***                                            ***
**************************************************
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/a/openssl'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/a/openssl'
Detected changed: Configure config build.info crypto/build.info ssl/build.info apps/build.info util/build.info tools/build.info fuzz/build.info providers/build.info doc/build.info test/build.info engines/build.info crypto/objects/build.info crypto/buffer/build.info crypto/bio/build.info crypto/stack/build.info crypto/lhash/build.info crypto/rand/build.info crypto/evp/build.info crypto/asn1/build.info crypto/pem/build.info crypto/x509/build.info crypto/conf/build.info crypto/txt_db/build.info crypto/pkcs7/build.info crypto/pkcs12/build.info crypto/ui/build.info crypto/kdf/build.info crypto/store/build.info crypto/property/build.info crypto/md4/build.info crypto/md5/build.info crypto/sha/build.info crypto/mdc2/build.info crypto/hmac/build.info crypto/ripemd/build.info crypto/whrlpool/build.info crypto/poly1305/build.info crypto/siphash/build.info crypto/sm3/build.info crypto/des/build.info crypto/aes/build.info crypto/rc2/build.info crypto/rc4/build.info crypto/idea/build.info crypto/aria/build.info crypto/bf/build.info crypto/cast/build.info crypto/camellia/build.info crypto/seed/build.info crypto/sm4/build.info crypto/chacha/build.info crypto/modes/build.info crypto/bn/build.info crypto/ec/build.info crypto/rsa/build.info crypto/dsa/build.info crypto/dh/build.info crypto/sm2/build.info crypto/dso/build.info crypto/engine/build.info crypto/err/build.info crypto/comp/build.info crypto/http/build.info crypto/ocsp/build.info crypto/cms/build.info crypto/ts/build.info crypto/srp/build.info crypto/cmac/build.info crypto/ct/build.info crypto/async/build.info crypto/ess/build.info crypto/crmf/build.info crypto/cmp/build.info crypto/encode_decode/build.info crypto/ffc/build.info apps/lib/build.info providers/common/build.info providers/implementations/build.info doc/man1/build.info providers/common/der/build.info providers/implementations/digests/build.info providers/implementations/ciphers/build.info providers/implementations/rands/build.info providers/implementations/macs/build.info providers/implementations/kdfs/build.info providers/implementations/exchange/build.info providers/implementations/keymgmt/build.info providers/implementations/signature/build.info providers/implementations/asymciphers/build.info providers/implementations/encode_decode/build.info providers/implementations/storemgmt/build.info providers/implementations/kem/build.info providers/implementations/rands/seeding/build.info Configurations/00-base-templates.conf Configurations/10-main.conf Configurations/15-android.conf
/usr/bin/perl configdata.pm -r
Configuring OpenSSL version 3.1.2 for target android-arm
Using os-specific seed configuration
Created configdata.pm
Running configdata.pm
Created Makefile.in
Created Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL.md file first)      ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
**************************************************
***                                            ***
***   Please run the same make command again   ***
***                                            ***
**************************************************
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/a/openssl'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/a/openssl'
Detected changed: Configure config build.info crypto/build.info ssl/build.info apps/build.info util/build.info tools/build.info fuzz/build.info providers/build.info doc/build.info test/build.info engines/build.info crypto/objects/build.info crypto/buffer/build.info crypto/bio/build.info crypto/stack/build.info crypto/lhash/build.info crypto/rand/build.info crypto/evp/build.info crypto/asn1/build.info crypto/pem/build.info crypto/x509/build.info crypto/conf/build.info crypto/txt_db/build.info crypto/pkcs7/build.info crypto/pkcs12/build.info crypto/ui/build.info crypto/kdf/build.info crypto/store/build.info crypto/property/build.info crypto/md4/build.info crypto/md5/build.info crypto/sha/build.info crypto/mdc2/build.info crypto/hmac/build.info crypto/ripemd/build.info crypto/whrlpool/build.info crypto/poly1305/build.info crypto/siphash/build.info crypto/sm3/build.info crypto/des/build.info crypto/aes/build.info crypto/rc2/build.info crypto/rc4/build.info crypto/idea/build.info crypto/aria/build.info crypto/bf/build.info crypto/cast/build.info crypto/camellia/build.info crypto/seed/build.info crypto/sm4/build.info crypto/chacha/build.info crypto/modes/build.info crypto/bn/build.info crypto/ec/build.info crypto/rsa/build.info crypto/dsa/build.info crypto/dh/build.info crypto/sm2/build.info crypto/dso/build.info crypto/engine/build.info crypto/err/build.info crypto/comp/build.info crypto/http/build.info crypto/ocsp/build.info crypto/cms/build.info crypto/ts/build.info crypto/srp/build.info crypto/cmac/build.info crypto/ct/build.info crypto/async/build.info crypto/ess/build.info crypto/crmf/build.info crypto/cmp/build.info crypto/encode_decode/build.info crypto/ffc/build.info apps/lib/build.info providers/common/build.info providers/implementations/build.info doc/man1/build.info providers/common/der/build.info providers/implementations/digests/build.info providers/implementations/ciphers/build.info providers/implementations/rands/build.info providers/implementations/macs/build.info providers/implementations/kdfs/build.info providers/implementations/exchange/build.info providers/implementations/keymgmt/build.info providers/implementations/signature/build.info providers/implementations/asymciphers/build.info providers/implementations/encode_decode/build.info providers/implementations/storemgmt/build.info providers/implementations/kem/build.info providers/implementations/rands/seeding/build.info Configurations/00-base-templates.conf Configurations/10-main.conf Configurations/15-android.conf
/usr/bin/perl configdata.pm -r
Configuring OpenSSL version 3.1.2 for target android-arm
Using os-specific seed configuration
Created configdata.pm
Running configdata.pm
Created Makefile.in
Created Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL.md file first)      ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
**************************************************
***                                            ***
***   Please run the same make command again   ***
***                                            ***
**************************************************
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/a/openssl'
```

Comment: I don't quite grasp the PowerShell script, but it looks like the `{cwd}/openssl` isn't being recognized as a valid folder according to the output.
What do you mean by `I run the setup within make` PowerShell script is intended to run in terminal! If your goal is to make things more consistent and compatible, you might want to stick with using only CMake. This could make your process smoother and prevent any potential problems that can come with using different scripting languages.

Comment: @Abdo21 By `I run the setup within make` I mean im running it in a [makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) with the make command. And if I cant get make to build openssl then I shouldn't even dream of using cmake probably.

Comment: I don't understand: why are you running make 3 times?  And, where is the output generated by the top-level make?  I don't see it anywhere in your quoted output.  You should really always and only use `$(MAKE)` not `make` when invoking sub-makes.  When you run the top-level make are you adding anything like `-j` or `-O` or similar options?

Comment: @MadScientist Im running make 3 times to show that the error suggestion (`Please run the same make command again`) dosent work. I turnacated the output since the error is the same 3 times (thats what I ment by `
... and then the same two more times`). I tried using the `$(MAKE)` variable but since its the same as  just having `make` it did not make a difference. I am also not using any flags like `-j` or `-O`, just `-B` to get it to work. :(

Comment: I don't see that message anywhere in the output you've provided

Comment: @MadScientist ok, now the output is repeated 3 times, does this help?

Comment: Well there you go.  `-B` is definitely going to break things.  It's one of those options which is really only meant to be used in extreme situations.  I don't know what you mean by "get it to work", but `-B` says: _Unconditionally make all targets._ which means it's always going to remake everything.  I don't know exactly how the sub-make is detecting "something changed", but since you pass `-B` it's always going to rebuild everything so that check is going to fire every time, because every time you run it "something changed".  Don't use `-B`.

Comment: OHHhhh, you are correct! It really was `-B`! I havent been using makefiles for long and I kept getting `X is up to date` and didnt know about `.PHONY` so I just assumed that `-B` was the only correct way to do it! Thank you so much! Would you care to add it as an answer so I can give you the bounty? @MadScientist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using `-B` on the `make` command line.  By giving this option, you are asking `make` to always rebuild everything in the makefile every time it runs.  Recall also that options like that are passed down to sub-makes (they have to be since else you would not be rebuilding the entire project) and so that means the make instances your rules invoke also get `-B` and they also rebuild everything all the time.

Because everything is always rebuilt, the "Detected changed" check in these makefiles thinks they are always being changed (which they are) and so it always reports this message.

You don't make clear why you wanted to use `-B` but if, for example, you have a subdirectory named `openssl` then the target:

```
openssl:
```

with no prerequisites will always be satisfied, because `openssl` exists in the current directory and there's no prerequisite to cause it to be considered out of date.  You can rename the target in your makefile to be something that doesn't exist in the directory, or use .PHONY (among other methods) to force make to rebuild that specific target every time.